# What if there are multiple customers that you want to return

Tags: sql-server

What if there are multiple customers that you want to return

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIPTION,
    item,
    cust_code,
    pack_description,
    uos,
    pack,
    total_value,
    total_value_vat,
    total_value_goods,
    price_indicator
from TRANSACTION_DETAILS
where cust_code=1273 
    and item in
    (
        371355,
        371476,
        371629,
        370556,
        370677,
        370820,
        370952,
        371070,
        371223,
        372154,
        372253,
        371751,
        371872
    )
```

Comment: may you please provide more information, thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an `IN` clause, the same way you are doing it for the `item` code:

```
WHERE cust_code IN (
      1273 
    , 1274
    , 1275
    )
AND item IN
(
      371355
    , 371476
    , 371629
    , 370556
    , 370677
    , 370820
    , 370952
    , 371070
    , 371223
    , 372154
    , 372253
    , 371751
    , 371872
)
```

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this.  Add details about exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and you'll get a better answer.

If you need a variable list of customers and items in your `WHERE` clause, a better way to do this may be through the use of temporary tables, as in the following example.

We'll use tempdb for this work to avoid impacting anything "important", and I'll create name the main table `TransactionDetails`.  Notice I'm [specifying the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), `dbo`, to eliminate any doubt about which table I'm referencing.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TransactionDetails
(
    ItemDescription varchar(30)
    , item int NOT NULL
    , cust_code int NOT NULL
    , pack_description varchar(38)
    , uos varchar(42)
    , pack varchar(6)
    , total_value decimal(18,4)
    , total_value_vat decimal(18,4)
    , total_value_goods decimal(18,4)
    , price_indicator bit

) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Here, I'll create two [temporary tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx#Anchor_4), one to hold the list of desired customers, and one for the list of desired items:

```
CREATE TABLE #CustList
(
    cust_code int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #CustList (cust_code)
VALUES (1273)
    , (1274)
    , (1275);

CREATE TABLE #Itemlist
(
    item int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Itemlist (item)
VALUES    (371355)
        , (371476)
        , (371629)
        , (370556)
        , (370677)
        , (370820)
        , (370952)
        , (371070)
        , (371223)
        , (372154)
        , (372253)
        , (371751)
        , (371872);
```

Now, the `SELECT` statement can employ `INNER JOIN` to efficiently return only the rows we're interested in:

```
SELECT 
    td.ItemDescription
    , td.item
    , td.cust_code
    , td.pack_description
    , td.uos
    , td.pack
    , td.total_value
    , td.total_value_vat
    , td.total_value_goods
    , td.price_indicator
FROM dbo.TransactionDetails td
    INNER JOIN #CustList cl ON td.cust_code = cl.cust_code
    INNER JOIN #Itemlist il ON td.item = il.item;
```